# How can I convince Highcharts to display the right (mine) steps on yaxis?

Tags: highcharts, label, axis

I'd like to display the yaxis as a ranking, that is it should display 1, 2, 3, .... What it does is, it displays 2, 4, 6. I put "step: 1", but this doesn't help. 
I don't succeed in convincing Highcharts to do it differently... Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/8GbL3/).

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
allowDecimals:false,
labels:
{
    step: 0.5
}
```

with

```
tickInterval: 1
```

Thanks

Paul.

Comment: Thanks a lot PaulG and vinod_vh!

Comment: Were you? I declared your response as the right answer, and upvoted the other answer, as that was right as well. I am not so familiar with the stackoverflow-voting-system...